# How to add appcache plugin?

Tags: webpack, preact

I just created a simple app with `preact create default helloworld` and now I need to add a `manifest.appcache` to it. How to do that?

What I have tried:

I found something called `appcache-webpack-plugin` and installed it with `npm i appcache-webpack-plugin`. Now I must probably `require()` it? But how, where?

https://github.com/lettertwo/appcache-webpack-plugin

Also was looking for a sort of Webpack config, because I read that preact uses Webpack, but there is no any config around in the project dir.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `src/template.html` and copy & paste this into it:
https://github.com/developit/preact-cli/blob/master/src/resources/template.html

Then add your manifest attribute to `<html>`.

You might need to modify your package.json script to pass `--template src/template.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I added this `preact.config.js` to my project.

```
var AppCachePlugin = require('appcache-webpack-plugin');

var manifest = new AppCachePlugin({
    cache: ['*'],
    network: ['/login'],
    fallback: [],
    output: 'manifest.appcache'
})

export default function (config, env, helpers) {
    console.log('AppCachePlugin loaded')
    var fs = require('fs')
    config.plugins.push(manifest)
}
```

Although I still do not know how to modify index.html to include `<html manifest=manifest.appcache>`